# Is move_uploaded_file in PHP atomic?

Tags: php, atomic

I have read on a [PHP's website](https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents#82934) that `file_put_contents` is not atomic. I was planning to use that to upload a file.

I was then wondering about the atomicity of `move_uploaded_file`, but could not find any information.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: The question if confusing. You say that the manual says it is not atomic, but still wonder about the atomicity of the function? There is a comment on that same page you posted with an atomic version.

Comment: @AzizSaleh I was referring to `file_put_contents` - check my edit.

Comment: Excuse my brains. Haven't had enough sleep.

Comment: @think123 can you stop deleting your questions after you get a few comments, its annoying; thanks.

Comment: @Dagon Won't delete this one, as it is of proper use to me.

Comment: Its obvious that you cannot expect automicity , because all web technologies rely on internet connection . I think there is no way to directly drop a file to the server or write a file to the server from client in a single shot.

Comment: It is possible however to prevent a second code to read that file until its done writing etc.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Well then would it be considered a random access solution?

Comment: You mean on shared read/write or upload / reading

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara How about setting ignore_user_abort to true, which will make the request complete regardless of the internet connection. The only downside is server side intermittent issues.

Comment: Aha, random access solution works but still you should have proper validation based so that if the file is not completely read then you should stop and ask the client to re upload or notify the client

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara No, I'm asking is `move_uploaded_file` considered random access?

Comment: i think you have to share your definition of 'random access' here

Comment: @Dagon So like, does the `move_uploaded_file` function have access to every character of the file, or is it read sequentially?

Comment: i would bet on sequentially, lets go check the source ...

Comment: I am sure there is a misconception here. Actually the random access concept is used to read the file. Move_uploaded_file is used to move the uploaded file to a specific destination.

Comment: Also you are trying to fputscontents, then why do you need random access .

Comment: move_uploaded_file reads the source file and copies it over to the destination file. This is the method it uses: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/main/streams/streams.c#1501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean atomic at a file-system level. It comes down to depending on your filesystem.

The process that happens with `move_uploaded_files` is basically:

- Can files be uploaded?
- Were two strings passed in?
- Was the source file uploaded?
- Does `open_basedir` allow writing to the destination?

Assuming all of those return a yes, then a `rename` is tried. On most filesystems, a rename is atomic.

If the `rename` failed, a copy and delete is then tried. This isn't atomic, as copying requires reading and then there's a separate delete.

Finally, if neither the rename nor the copy worked, an error is generated instead.

Comment: "Can files be uploaded?" --- what's this?